# Set anchor based on it's child value

Tags: javascript, jquery

List of links would look something like this

```
<a href="#">
  <strong>Application</strong>
</a>

<a href="#">
  <strong>Application Review</strong>
</a>
```

Each link should have the correct anchor, so e.g. first anchor should be `#application`. Maybe also somehow become lowercase?

edit: I also just realized second item has space, so anchor for it should be something like `#application-review`?

Or am I overreaching?

Comment: What would they actually point to? Because _that_ is what you want to generate links for. Just generating `<a href="#somefragment">` just gives you a link that doesn't go anywhere if that fragment id doesn't exist on your page. Also, don't use `<strong>` if you want bold text, instead assign your links the proper styling using regular CSS.

Comment: You're right, I forgot I need to apply ID too, but I guess that's another question. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is certainly possible.**

Try using this code:

```
$("a").each(function() {
    $(this).prop('href', '#' + $(this).children('strong').html());
});
```

The `.each(function() {...});` part loops through every anchor element.
Then for every anchor we get the child `<strong>` element's body contents. We take those body contents and change the `href` `prop` to it.

Don't forget to include the `#` in the `href` `prop`!

To make strings lowercase just use the `toLowerCase()` method on a String object.

```
var s = 'FOO'.toLowerCase();
console.log(s);
// > foo
```

**Edit:** you can use the `replaceAll()` method on a String object to replace a substring. To make the anchors work with spaces use following code:

```
var s = "string with spaces".replaceAll(' ', '%20');
console.log(s);
// > string%20with%20spaces
```

The %20 represents a space in URLs.

Comment: Hi, this works so far, but I don't think spaces are supported. Any idea how to replace space with `%20` or underscore `_`?

Comment: Actually I solved that part with `.replace(/ /g,"_")`

Comment: Sorry! Skipped over that. Please view the edited version of my answer which includes a way to replace all occurences of a space with `%20` - which represents a space in URLs.

Comment: Looks like we're typing at same time. Would you say your solution is better for spaces than `.replace(/ /g,"_")`?

Comment: Mind that by using `.replace(/ /g,"_")` you will only replace the FIRST instance of a space. Try using `replaceAll()` for optimal results.

Comment: It's up to you to use `%20` or `_`.

Comment: Would you say I'm missing anything in this approach https://jsfiddle.net/qyr0xk1e/ so far it looks good. If you hover it shows correct anchors.

Comment: Looks good to me. If you found my answer helpful please consider marking it as accepted!

Comment: Spaces don't make sense in the anchor hash since an ID can't include spaces